# Box android sample code does not run properly

Tags: android, box

This is a question for Box team, but I want to ask publicly so that others can benefit.

As a registered developer of Box's sdk, I downloaded the sample android app from github https://github.com/box/box-android-sdk-v2, and followed the
instruction from https://developers.box.com/android-sdk-tutorial/

=============
Here is what I did:

1. I set the following information correctly in HelloWorldApplication.java:

public static final String CLIENT_ID = "xxxxxxx";

public static final String CLIENT_SECRET = "yyyyyy";

public static final String REDIRECT_URL ="boxsdk-xxxxxxx://boxsdkoauth2redirect";

1. Then I ran Helloworld2 from Android's eclipse.

It displays an activity for me to log in to Evernote and grant access to it.

1. After I click on Grant Access, it returns me back to the main activity.

It displays the following: "failure: the protocol is not supported."

==========================
I tried to understand the error means redirect URL is not https, but I
am running inside an Android App, so that is obviously not an real
error.

Can someone point out a valid way to run your sample app?

Thanks so much.

Regards,
Howard

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the error is related to URL setting, yours is

> public static final String REDIRECT_URL
>   ="boxsdk-xxxxxxx://boxsdkoauth2redirect";

as a comparison, my application uses below definition.

> public static final String REDIRECT_URL ="http://localhost";

I suppose only http and https protocols are supported in OATH2 protocol, and the REDIRECT_URL should be same with the one you set on the Box Console page.